Создание справки в Eclipse
Мне необходимо создать плагин справки в Eclipse, который можно будет встраивать в другие проекты и запускать в браузере.
В интернете я увидел способ чтобы сервер и плагин "объединяло" RCP приложение. Я создал RCP и встроил туда справку, но я без понятия какие действия мне дальше предпринимать.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.


нужно добавить в приложение нужные зависимости для справки (org.eclipse.help, org.eclipse.help.ui).
в ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor добавь запуск справочного сервера через HelpSystem.setMode(HelpSystem.MODE_INFOCENTER).
справка будет доступна через http://localhost:<порт>/help. Порт можно указать через конфигурации help.server.port в файле plugin_customization.ini.
чтобы другие проекты могли использовать плагин справки без полного RCP, создай автономный доступ. Это достигается путем создания специальной ссылки на справку или встроенной инструкции для запуска RCP через браузер.


Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему может быть такая ошибка
Description Resource Path Location Type
MODE_INFOCENTER cannot be resolved or is not a field ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor.java
/First RCP Application/src/first/rcp/application line 23 Java Problem
Мой код:
import org.eclipse.help.HelpSystem;
@Override
public void postWindowOpen(IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer) {
HelpSystem.setMode(HelpSystem.MODE_INFOCENTER);
}

MODE_INFOCENTER cannot be resolved or is not a field — возникает, потому что вы пытаетесь использовать константу MODE_INFOCENTER, которая не является доступной в HelpSystem в вашем случае. надо добавить следующие зависимости в MANIFEST.MF:
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.help, org.eclipse.help.ui
файл plugin_customization.ini должен содержать следующие строку
help.server.port=<ваш_порт>

Простите, что отвечаю спустя длительное время, я не нашел у себя файла plugin_customization.ini, поэтому создал его в корневом каталоге RCP, записал туда лишь строчку help.server.port=8081, но ошибка до сих пор осталась: Description Resource Path Location Type
MODE_INFOCENTER cannot be resolved or is not a field ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor.java /First RCP Application/src/first/rcp/application line 24 Java Problem. Нужно ли что-нибудь еще добавлять в файл plugin_customization.ini?

В конечном итоге я заменил HelpSystem на BaseHelpSystem, у меня получилось @Override      public void postWindowOpen(IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer) { BaseHelpSystem.setMode(BaseHelpSystem.MODE_INFOCENTER); } но на справку это все еще никак не повлияло, могли бы вы подсказать, как я могу использовать данный метод?
